# How to use the Copy-Item cmdlet correctly to copy piped files

Tags: powershell, copy, powershell-2.0

I am building a small script which should copy all `.zip` files to a special folder called  `F:\tempzip`.

I tried it with [Copy-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx) cmdlet, but I didn't manage to do it. The script should copy all files from this folder (recursively) which are ".zip".

This is the part of the script I am talking about:

```
get-childitem F:\Work\xxx\xxx\xxx -recurse `
   | where {$_.extension -eq ".zip"}       `
   | copy-item F:\tempzip
```

What do I have to add?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When piping items to `copy-item` you need to tell it that `"F:\tempzip"` is the destination path.

```
| Copy-Item -Destination F:\tempzip
```

You can also cutout piping to the `where` operator by using `Get-ChildItem`'s parameter `-filter`.

```
Get-Childitem "C:\imscript" -recurse -filter "*.zip" | Copy-Item -Destination "F:\tempzip"
```

**Edit**: Removal of unnecessary `foreach` loop and updated explanation.

Comment: I believe that adding a filter to the get-childitem commandlet is more efficient than filtering the results: Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip -Recurse

Comment: i can't use filter, because it's just a part of my script. i copy many zip files which are created in different subfolders. so i need a recursive search. with your fullpath it worked :) thank you. with filter it didnt work. so i still have my recursive search

Comment: Copy-Item should be smart enough to handle a FileInfo object, actually, so you wouldn't need the `.FullName` there.

Answer (score 13):

It's a lot simpler than that. **Copy-Item** has its own **-Recurse** switch. All you have to do is:

```
Copy-Item F:\Work\xxx\xxx\xxx\*.zip F:\tempzip -Recurse
```

Comment: Yes it does have a built in recures switch but you need to activate it using the `-recurse` parameter. Also trying to filter at the folder path doesn’t work very well with `copy-item` you are better of using the `-filter ` param. So it would look something like this `Copy-Item F:\Work\xxx\xxx\xxx\ F:\tempzip -Recurse -filter *.zip` But this will copy the folder and its subfolders not just the .zip files into the destination folder

Comment: How sloppy - the whole point of my answer is that Copy-Item has its own **-Recurse** switch, but I left out the **-Recurse** switch. :) I fixed the answer.

Comment: Makes a little more sense now :)

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason, the Copy-Item recursion didn't accomplish what I wanted, as mentioned here, and how it is documented to work.  If you have a bunch of *.zip or *.jpg files in arbitrarily deep subfolder hierarchies, and you want to copy them to a single place (one flat folder, elsewhere), I had better luck with a piped command involving Get-ChildItem.  Say you are currently in the folder containing the root of your search:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.zip | Copy-Item -Destination C:\Someplace\Else
```

That command will copy all the files and not duplicate the folder hierarchies.

Comment: This is what I needed, copy all files of a type recursively to a flat structure.