# Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item explanation

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

Why does

```
gci $from -Recurse | copy-item -Destination  $to -Recurse -Force -Container
```

not behave in the same way as

```
copy-item $from $to -Recurse -Force
```

?

I think it should be the same, but somehow it's not. Why?

Comment: what is the difference? the second script is not copying recursively? here one guy helped me using % foreach to copy all output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972783/how-to-use-the-copy-item-cmdlet-correctly

Answer (score 21):

You are not looping over each item in the collection of files/folders, but passing the last value to the pipe.  You need to use Foreach-item or % to the Copy-Item command.  From there, you also do not need the second -recurse switch as you already have every item in the GCI.

try this:

```
gci $from -Recurse | % {copy-item -Path $_ -Destination  $to -Force -Container }
```

Comment: shouldn't `gci $from -Recurse` get all files from directory and them pipe thru

Comment: Isn't the copy-item missing a `$_`? This is not running for me in PS 5.0
The actual command is:

`gci $from -Recurse | % { copy-item $_ -Destination $to -Force }`

Comment: You are correct kumar_harsh that I neglected the $_ in my original answer.  I've made this slight revisions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Recurse -Include *.txt | %{Join-Path -Path $_.Directory -ChildPath $_.Name } | Copy-Item -Destination $to
```

Comment: No need to `Join-Path`, use `$_.FullName` in `Copy-Item` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\source\' -Recurse | % {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'd:\Dest\' -Force -Container }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of why this answers the question.

Comment: perhaps it doesn't directly but might be helpful to those wishing to understand more about the various ways in which you can achieve the same outcome in different ways.

Answer (score -1):

The switches are wrong. They should be:

```
gci -Path $from -Recurse | copy-item -Destination  $to -Force -Container
```

Answer (score -1):

To loop all items, this should work:

```
gci -Path $from -Recurse | % { $_ | copy-item -Destination  $to -Force -Container}
```

Just do the foreach and pipe each item again.